# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'1

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extend`enter code here`s StatelessWidget {
  // const ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Function sel`enter code here`ectHandler ;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Text('Pink'),
         // textColor: Colors.pink,
          onPressed:selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

hey guys please help me to solve this i am having issue in this code @ onPressed:selectHandler

Comment: final Function() selectHandler;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use voidcallback

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
   const ({Key? key, this.selectHandler}) : super(key: key);
  final VoidCallback selectHandler ;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Text('Pink'),
         // textColor: Colors.pink,
          onPressed:selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use GestureTapCallback. Hope that work for you

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Answer extend StatelessWidget {
  // const ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final GestureTapCallback selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Text('Pink'),
         // textColor: Colors.pink,
          onPressed:selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```